# Why is GitHub's Atom autocomplete suggesting symbols with one character truncated from the end?

Tags: autocomplete, atom-editor

i'm not sure why/when this started, but frequently I get an auto-suggestion for a value that exists in my code, but with the last letter missing. It's not one single case, it happens a lot.

[image: Screenshot showing two suggestions, getDraftValu and getDraftValue]

I'm running version 1.6.0

Here's my package list:

```
Built-in Atom packages (89)
├── about@1.3.0
├── archive-view@0.61.0
├── atom-dark-syntax@0.27.0
├── atom-dark-ui@0.51.0
├── atom-light-syntax@0.28.0
├── atom-light-ui@0.43.0
├── autocomplete-atom-api@0.10.0
├── autocomplete-css@0.11.0
├── autocomplete-html@0.7.2
├── autocomplete-plus@2.25.0
├── autocomplete-snippets@1.10.0
├── autoflow@0.27.0
├── autosave@0.23.0
├── background-tips@0.26.0
├── base16-tomorrow-dark-theme@1.1.0
├── base16-tomorrow-light-theme@1.1.1
├── bookmarks@0.38.2
├── bracket-matcher@0.79.0
├── command-palette@0.38.0
├── deprecation-cop@0.54.0
├── dev-live-reload@0.47.0
├── encoding-selector@0.21.0
├── exception-reporting@0.37.0
├── find-and-replace@0.197.4
├── fuzzy-finder@0.94.0
├── git-diff@0.57.0
├── go-to-line@0.30.0
├── grammar-selector@0.48.0
├── image-view@0.56.0
├── incompatible-packages@0.25.0
├── keybinding-resolver@0.33.0
├── language-c@0.51.1
├── language-clojure@0.19.1
├── language-coffee-script@0.46.0
├── language-csharp@0.11.0
├── language-css@0.36.0
├── language-gfm@0.84.0
├── language-git@0.12.1
├── language-go@0.42.0
├── language-html@0.44.0
├── language-hyperlink@0.16.0
├── language-java@0.17.0
├── language-javascript@0.110.0
├── language-json@0.17.4
├── language-less@0.29.0
├── language-make@0.21.0
├── language-mustache@0.13.0
├── language-objective-c@0.15.1
├── language-perl@0.32.0
├── language-php@0.37.0
├── language-property-list@0.8.0
├── language-python@0.43.0
├── language-ruby@0.68.0
├── language-ruby-on-rails@0.25.0
├── language-sass@0.45.0
├── language-shellscript@0.21.0
├── language-source@0.9.0
├── language-sql@0.20.0
├── language-text@0.7.0
├── language-todo@0.27.0
├── language-toml@0.18.0
├── language-xml@0.34.2
├── language-yaml@0.25.1
├── line-ending-selector@0.3.0
├── link@0.31.0
├── markdown-preview@0.157.2
├── metrics@0.53.1
├── notifications@0.62.1
├── one-dark-syntax@1.2.0
├── one-dark-ui@1.1.9
├── one-light-syntax@1.2.0
├── one-light-ui@1.1.9
├── open-on-github@0.41.0
├── package-generator@0.41.0
├── settings-view@0.232.3
├── snippets@1.0.1
├── solarized-dark-syntax@1.0.0
├── solarized-light-syntax@1.0.0
├── spell-check@0.65.0
├── status-bar@0.83.0
├── styleguide@0.45.1
├── symbols-view@0.110.1
├── tabs@0.91.3
├── timecop@0.33.0
├── tree-view@0.203.2
├── update-package-dependencies@0.10.0
├── welcome@0.33.0
├── whitespace@0.32.1
└── wrap-guide@0.38.1

/Users/me/.atom/packages (26)
├── Stylus@1.0.0
├── activate-power-mode@0.4.1
├── atom-beautify@0.28.24
├── atom-jade@0.3.0
├── atom-material-ui@0.8.0
├── auto-indent@0.5.0
├── autoclose-html@0.22.0
├── emmet@2.4.1
├── file-icons@1.6.19
├── git-diff-details@0.20.0
├── highlight-selected@0.11.2
├── idiomatic-dark-syntax@0.1.3
├── language-cjsx@0.3.0
├── language-javascript-jsx@0.3.7
├── linter@1.11.3
├── linter-coffeelint@1.1.2
├── linter-eslint@5.2.6
├── merge-conflicts@1.3.2
├── pigments@0.26.0
├── predawn-ui@1.0.2
├── pretty-json@0.4.1
├── react@0.14.1
├── react-snippets@0.1.4
├── seti-ui@0.8.1
├── spacegray-dark-neue-ui@1.4.0
└── spacegray-dark-ui@0.12.0
```

Comment: Could you share which version of Atom you are using, and which packages are installed.  It's possibly a defect and as such if we can reproduce it we can look to fixing it.

Comment: sure, updated, thanks

Comment: That is, shall we say, "odd".  I cannot reproduce from my machine,.could you start atom in safe mode by running `atom --safe` from your terminal and see if the issue is still there.  If it is still there then can I humbly suggest you create a bug report in the atom/autocomplete-plus repository using the following as guidance: https://github.com/atom/atom/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#reporting-bugs

Comment: Been happening to me too.

Comment: @johncip what version of Atom are you using, does running atom in safe mode (`atom --safe`) make any difference?

Comment: My atom version is 1.6.1. On further inspection, this seems only to happen in CJSX files. OP and I both have language-cjsx installed. @Ben, can you find an instance of this happening with a symbol that wasn't grabbed from CJSX source?

Comment: Confirmed that this is an issue witht he `language-cjsx` package, I have installed it and can reproduce it on any CoffeeScript file while `language-cjsx` is loaded.

Comment: Thanks @RichardSlater for narrowing down the cause. I submitted an issue and may take a crack at figuring this out as well https://github.com/ghempton/language-cjsx/issues/9

Comment: Thanks @Ben - I had a quick look but couldn't get my head around what was going on.  Look forward to someone figuring this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out this is a defect in the [language-cjsx](https://github.com/ghempton/language-cjsx) package.  If you open the Chrome Developer Tools with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> and inspect the function name tokens as identified by the grammar there is an unnecessary `span` element surrounding the last character of every function name.

I have managed to solve this in my fork by simply [removing the mapping between one of the capture groups and the grammar class](https://github.com/RichardSlater/language-cjsx/commit/e3f57a0fac347ae8d4765da3ca3b2403d917a249).  Whilst this works, a more elegant solution from Víctor Martínez is available that incorporates all of the recent changes [from the CoffeeScript grammar package](https://github.com/knoopx/language-cjsx).

If you want to test this out you can follow the following process:

1. Uninstall the existing version of the `language-cjsx` package.
2. Clone one of the above two forks of `language-cjsx` to a known directory.
3. Run `apm link <path-to-directory>` to symlink the package to Atom's package directory.
4. Restart Atom with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>.

**Final Note**: Víctor Martínez [has subsequently noted](https://github.com/ghempton/language-cjsx/pull/10#issuecomment-203516459) that he is currently using [orktes/atom-react](https://github.com/orktes/atom-react/) to obtain syntax highlighting for CJSX based solutions.